# R - column from string in dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr

my dataframe look like this

```
x <-
  data.frame(
    id = c("123_1", "987_123")
  )
```

I'd like to create this result dataframe via dplyr mutate function. I just want to take first part before underscore sign and another one right after underscore sign.

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    id = c("123_1", "987_123"),
    af = c("123", "987"),
    ad = c("1", "123")
  )
```

Comment: One option: `x[, c("af", "ad")] <- data.table::tstrsplit(x$id, "_")`

Comment: Or with `tidyr separate(x, id, into = c("af", "ad"), remove = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) tidyverse** Use `separate` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  separate(id, c("af", "ad"), remove = FALSE)
##        id  af  ad
## 1   123_1 123   1
## 2 987_123 987 123
```

**2) Base R**

**2a) read.table** Without any packages use `read.table`

```
cbind(x, read.table(text = x$id, sep = "_", col.names = c("af", "ad"),
  colClasses = "character"))
##        id  af  ad
## 1   123_1 123   1
## 2 987_123 987 123
```

**2b) sub** or use `sub`:

```
transform(x, af = sub("_.*", "", id), ad = sub(".*_", "", id))
##        id  af  ad
## 1   123_1 123   1
## 2 987_123 987 123
```

Comment: Longer, but there's also `strcapture`: `cbind(x, strcapture("(.*)_(.*)", x$id, data.frame(af = character(), ad = character())))`